# Iterating over a Json File in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I import a json file into my TypeScript file and I am not sure how to iterate over it.

The error message states:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of
type 'string' can't be used to index type...
```

**My Json file**

```
{
    "foo": false,
    "bar": false,
}
```

**My code:**

```
import * as emails from './test_emails.json'

for (let v in emails) {
          emails[v]; <- access is the error here
}
```

Does anyone know whats going on here? I am wondering how I can make `emails[v]` return the boolean value. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you have correct keys when you are asking for `v`. Why not just print `v` first and see if it makes sense. Also, is `emails` non-empty?

Comment: `emails` is not empty, and `v` contains the email address

Comment: If you only want to get the values of the object than use `Object.values(emails)`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way

**JSON**

```
{
 "emails" : [
   {
    "foo": "false",
    "bar": "false",
   }
 ]
}
```

**Typescript**

```
import * as data from './test_emails.json';
public emails: IEmail [] = data.emails;   // Make sure to import IEmail


for (let v in emails) {
          console.log(v.foo);
          console.log(v.bar);   // Do whatever you want I just printed on console
}
```

**Interface**

```
export interface IEmail
{
foo : boolean;
bar : boolean;
}
```